# Anonymous method in anonymous type not authorized?

Tags: c#

i try to create a call like this, which works well in javascript:

```
service.DoAction(new { param1="sometext", onOk= () => { Console.WriteLine("ok"); }});
```

but it does not compile with error:

> Can not assign 'anonymous method' to anonymous type property

or

> Can not assign 'lambda expression' to anonymous type property

Any idea why this is not authorized ? Language limitation ?

Comment: It seems that the correct type cannot be inferred here. When you do `OnOk = new Action(() => {})`, it works.

Answer (score 6):

The idea of a lambda is that it cannot know the type of the delegate that represents the anonymous method without context.  It needs to be assigned to something that has a known delegate type so that the type of the delegate can be inferred.

The anonymous type property also needs to infer its type from what you assign to it.  They each are trying to infer the type from each other, and it's never specified anywhere.

You'll need to explicitly indicate the delegate type to use for it to compile:

```
var foo = new
{
    hi = "Hi!",
    doSomething = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("Done!"))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var test = new { hi = "Hi!", doSomething = (Action)(() => { Console.WriteLine("Done!"); }) };   
test.doSomething();
```

.NET itself definitely doesn't care - anonymous types and methods are compiled into "real" types and methods anyway, so there's no difference. Note that `doSomething` in this example is not a method on its own, it's just a reference to the method (which resides in it's own anonymous type). So you can't use `this`.

So; C# doesn't allow you to create complete anonymous types (like Java does) - you can't create a type that implements an interface and has methods (outside of properties, which *are* methods+ internally). This is a workaround that assigns a reference to an anonymous method to an auto-property on the anonymous type, and you have to concretize the type, because `() => {}` can mean a bunch of different types, and the compiler has to know one specific type.